# Voice chat in Unity 5 Unet

Tags: voip, unity-game-engine

I'm starting a project in Unity 5.3.2, something like a VR simulation, and I would like to integrate a voice chat. I've made my own research but all I found are deprecated scripts, such as [voice-chat](https://github.com/fholm/unityassets/tree/master/VoiceChat), do you have any interesting (preferably free) alternative for Unet to accomplish my goal?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully used that open-source project you mentioned with Unity 5.

If you take the master branch then it can work with Photon Networking.

However, for UNET you should take the Pull Request #5 branch:
https://github.com/fholm/unityassets/pull/5

You still need to actually wire it up with your networking code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check that out